# Tracking a game object transform - Why using FindGameObjectWithTag doesn't work?

Tags: c#, reference, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm following a tutorial (precisely the [survival shooter](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/enemy-one)), and I am at the stage to implement the NavMesh. Their original script is like this:

```
 Transform _player;
 NavMeshAgent nav;

 void Start()
 {
     _player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
     nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     nav.SetDestination(_player.position);     
 }
```

So far nothing special. I press play and strangely the enemy (I have only one at the moment in the scene) only reaches the initial position of the player (0,0,0) instead of following it around if player moves. I realized that position of the player is not updated in the `_player` field and it stays at `0,0,0`.

I tried a different approach: I dragged and dropped the Player's game object onto the property in the UI (I made the property public first and I changed it into a `GameObject`). In this case it works flawlessly:

```
 GameObject _player;
 NavMeshAgent nav;

 void Start()
 {
     //Player is not retrieved here as before, but it's passed assigning the GameObject to the property directly through the UI
     nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     nav.SetDestination(_player.transform.position);     
 }
```

At this stage I wonder:

Does `FindGameObjectWithTag` method make a copy of the object instead of returning a reference to the `GameObject`? Why it doesn't work in the first instance. I use Unity 5 by the way.

Comment: I recreated the situation and I do believe that FindGameObjectWithTag() returns a copy of the object at the time it is called. Reading the documentation on this method seems to confirm this since there is no mention of a reference.

Comment: The only thing i have in my head is that gameobject isn't active at the time so FindGameObjectWithTag wont detect it.

Comment: Something that might be worth trying is using the [`FindGameObjectsWithTag`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) and see if more than one thing is returned. Perhaps the one you get is like the prefab which isn't moving or something.

Comment: @UriPopov could you send me the link of the doc u read? I think I have missed it :/

Comment: @GregLukosek No it is active, but I will double check. Although the theory that it is a copy sounds  very plausible

Comment: If you put the inspector in "Debug" mode, click the button on the top right of the inspector that has three lines and an arrow, and select Debug.  From there you can see what transform is being referenced my clicking on the object next to _player

Comment: In the tutorial, they don't use `Start` but `Awake`. BTW, did you bake the NavMesh before entering the play mode?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have more than 1 object with the tag "Player" in the scene. I changed your code to detect this condition.

```
Transform _player;
NavMeshAgent nav;

void Start()
{
    GameObject[] playerObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    if(playerObjects.Length>1) 
    {
        Debug.LogError("You have multiple player objects in the scene!");
    }
    _player = playerObjects[0].transform;
    nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

void Update()
{
    nav.SetDestination(_player.position);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of different problem that may exists :

So here is what you should test :

- First you should try :
  `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();`
- If your player gameObject has an unique name, try to use

`Transform playerTransform = GameObject.Find("MyPlayerName").transform`

- If it still doesn't work, if this script is assign to your player, you can access the gameObject by using `this`
- If your script isn't attach to your player gameobject, you can set your player gameobject as a public attribute to your script. And then in the editor, grab your player gameobject and put it in the right case of your class attribute. In this case your declaration should be :

`public GameObject myPlayer;`

- But before testing any of these methods, you should test if the problem comes from the `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` by simply using your player name in this editor. Let assumes that your gameobject player name is MyFantasticPlayer. Then try this :

  ```
  `GameObject myPlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
  if(myPlayer.name == "MyFantasticPlayer")
  {
     Debug.Log("Not problem with FindGameObjectWithTag");
  }else{
  Debug.Log("Problem");
  }`
  ```

And if your Debug log says problem, maybe try to catch an exception.